# Python compresses entire directory rather than the sole files

Tags: python, directory, zip, compression, automator

I have written a python script which i use in automator to compress files. the problems is that when i compress them the entire directory(meaning all the folders) + the files are compressed rather than just the files by themselves. So if i ran this on my desktop with two files as args, test1 and test2 the output would be "Currentdate&time.zip" and when i extract it. it would look like this /Users/dean/desktop/test1
/Users/dean/desktop/test2

so it zips up all those folders when all i want is the files. please help

this code works greate when ran from terminal but not in automator (my comment below) i use this code as a service in automator. so one file works fine. multiple files dont btw len(sys.argv)>3 should really be len(sys.argv)>1

```
OSX_username = getpass.getuser()
now = datetime.datetime.today()
dir = os.getcwd()
zip_dir = dir + "/" + now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M") + '.zip'
dst_dir = "/Users/" + OSX_username + "/Desktop"
zf = zipfile.ZipFile(now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M") + '.zip', mode='w')

if len(sys.argv) > 3: #app 2 service 3
    for f in sys.argv[1:]:
        try:
            zf.write(f)
        finally:
            print ''
    zf.close()
    src = zip_dir
    last_part = os.path.basename(src)
    shutil.move(src, dst_dir)
```

Comment: Can you add an example usage? From just inspecting your code I would guess it's a problem in parsing the arguments, but I might be totally wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your for loop, Instead of this -

```
zf.write(f)
```

Try this -

```
zf.write(f, os.path.basename(f), zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
```

Comment: yes it works when i run the script from the terminal. No it doesnt work when i run the script in automator. the reason is when i run the script from terminal my args are test.txt and test1.txt. when i run it in automator my args become  /Users/dean/desktop/test1.txt & /Users/dean/desktop/test2.txt

Comment: @Dean - Try this,
`zf.write(f, os.path.basename(f), zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)`

Comment: yep that did it. Thankyou very much sir!!! If i had a score of 15 your vote would be sealed. Thanks again

Comment: @Dean - no problem! And please don't call me Sir, am too young :)